# Estimate height of atmosphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, estimation

Working on a estimation problem and we've been asked to estimate the height of the Earth's atmosphere given its mass is $10^{19}\mathrm{kg}$ and we must assume the density is $1\mathrm{\frac{{kg}}{m^3}}$

Stuck on where to begin with this.

Comment: The answer key gives the estimate of 3 * 10 ^4 m ~ 30km, just now sure how they arrived at that

Answer (score 1):

Given the mass and density you can find the volume required. Then try approximating the Earth as a sphere. You can calculate the volume of the atmosphere if it is, say, $1 km$ high: it's simply $4\pi/3 \times (R+1km)^3 - 4\pi/3 \times R^3$, where $R$ is the radius of the Earth. Adjust as necessary to match the volume required.

Comment: The point is to estimate the height of the atmosphere.  If we're given the mass and the density would the total volume be mass/density, which gives you 10^19kg / (1kg/m^3) which would then give you 10^19 m^3 ?

Comment: @dstarh the short answer is yes, but if you're asking that question I'd suggest making sure you're familiar with algebraic operations first before attempting more problems like this one.

Comment: I've taken calc, it's been a few semesters but I have the basics, just unsure how they're going from the given values to their answer of 3 * 10^4m .  I thought about taking the volume of earth + some theoretical height but it's that theoretical hight we're trying to ascertain.

Comment: @dstarh this isn't calculus, it's algebra. The theoretical height is the variable you're trying to solve for. If you look at the equation in my answer above, you can replace the $1km$ with a variable $x$, and solve for that, since you already know what $R$ is (if you don't, you can Google for the radius of the Earth).

Comment: thanks, I gotcha now

Comment: except you should use $V = (4\pi R^2) \times h$.